# Why do I get the error TypeError: $("#main-nav").dropmenu is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am experiencing a conflict of sorts between two jQuery scripts on this page: http://encoreazalea.com/ee/the-collection/in-the-landscape

I am using one script for the drop down menu and another one for the image gallery.

On the home page of the site there is no error. However, on this page I get the following Console error:

```
TypeError: $("#main-nav").dropmenu is not a function
zindex: 100
```

My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:has(img.gallery)").click(function() {
        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
        var caption = $(this).attr("title");
        jQuery(".photo_large").attr({ src: largePath});
        jQuery("#caption1").text(caption);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

I would appreciate some help sorting this out.

Thanks.

Comment: if you hit http://encoreazalea.com/ee/the-collection/js/jquery.dropmenu.js directly you get a html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://encoreazalea.com/ee/the-collection/js/jquery.dropmenu.js is not loaded properly

Comment: Brilliant. Such a simple mistake. Thank you.